# Root a Samsung Galaxy 4 tab 7", Kies isn't working

Tags: rooting, samsung-kies, samsung-galaxy-tab-4

I am trying to root a Samsung Galaxy 4 tab 7". The box says SM-T230NU with the label "Model: SM-T230NYKMXAR".

I got drivers from here:
http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SM-T230NYKUXAR
which is a slightly different number (has a U instead of M) but matches (ie. Samsung Galaxy Tab® 4 7.0 8GB, Black). I installed these and the device connected to the PC with no problems.

Using Odin 3.07, it detects the device. I click the PDA button and select `CF-Auto_Root.tar`, then Start and I get this error:

```
<ID:0/005> Firmware update start..  
<ID:0/005> recovery.img  
<ID:0/005> NAND Write Start!!   
<ID:0/005> cache.img.ext4  
<ID:0/005> FAIL!  
<OSM> All now when I restart I get this message:
```

Now when I restart I get this message:

```
Firmware upgrade encountered an issue.   
Please select recovery mode in Kies & try again.threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 1)
```

I downloaded and installed Kies 3. When I run it, it says "The connected device is not supported by Kies 3". It should be, this is 4.4 KitKat.

So I tried Kies 2.6, and it doesn't connect either. It doesn't give this error message, just keeps trying to connect but doesn't.

What can I do now?

Comment: Which CF-AutoRoot did you use? There's no official AutoRoot for that device on Chainfire's website. Also, did you unlock the bootloader first?

Comment: I used the CF-Auto-Root.tar that came in the Odin zip file. I don't know what you mean by 'unlock the bootloader'. I put the device in developer mode and checked USB debugging. Is that it?

Comment: Where did you get the zip from? Was it specifically for T230? Unlocked bootloader is a different thing and it's needed for CF-AutoRoot if used via Odin. See the [XDA Wiki](http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/Bootloader) for more info on bootloaders. It seems like CF-AutoRoot attempted to flash your cache but failed, and you'll need to flash back to stock before trying anything new.

Comment: >>flash back to stock before trying anything new ... how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Flash your stock ROM using Odin whilst your device is in
Download mode  <kbd>Power</kbd>  +  <kbd>Volume Down</kbd>  +  <kbd>Home</kbd>

(Put the file in the AP/PDA depending on what version of Odin you have). If this works then your tablet may be back to factory state, but if it fails then you have Hard bricked your tablet. Presuming it isnt bricked, use the latest .apk file of King Root to root your Sm-T230.

Stock Rom Download from XDA forums: [ACHERON ROM v2.1.1](http://forum.xda-developers.com/tab-4/development/rom-stock-t230-nu-acheron-rom-v1-0-2015-t3000107) and
[Odin 3 download](http://odindownload.com/)

Comment: Yes king root does worked for me (twice) on this device (sm-t230 7'')    Forum link: http://forum.freelatestmovies.org/tab-4/general/root-galaxy-tab-4-7-t230-t2835264/page41

Comment: Please edit your Answer to state this- not everyone reads comments!